# Discord.py bot not running on Heroku

Tags: heroku, discord.py

I have a simple discord bot made using python and I have deployed it on Heroku. My bot is running perfectly fine locally, but it never comes online. When I open my app, there is an application error.
I used the command: `heroku logs --tail --app my-bot` and this is the result I get:

> 2021-04-29T19:39:35.050215+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=telepathy-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=b5acbe5f-ba6f-40d3-a08c-915850f2d27f fwd="103.242.190.234" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2021-04-29T19:39:35.438642+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=telepathy-bot.herokuapp.com request_id=e5df6b77-b518-45a8-bbae-9e3f0d15126a fwd="103.242.190.234" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

I tried looking at many things. I ran the `heroku ps:scale worker=1` and also tried `heroku ps:scale web=1` but I have no luck. What should I do?

My Profile is as follows:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
heroku ps:scale worker=1
worker: python launcher.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use Heroku, use dynox hosting https://client.dynox.us/